# Items not staying in center of div on resize or not, keeps going offset

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center

Ive been trying to fix this issue for a pretty long time now, but for some reason, whenever I resize the page, this one div goes offset and fails to stay in the center. I made the text in the div unwrapped on purpose so that it doesnt interfere with the elements I will be adding later.

I already tried using `margin: 0 auto`, `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` on every element and off every element, experimenting to see which one would center it properly but none of them worked. I also tried using a 100% width parent element but that didn't work either.

I wouldn't want to use javascript in this case if just css is possible. If javascript is the best way to fix it then so be it.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbg1d947/) that shows the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already on center, for horizontally center `margin: 0 auto` is working as expected. The problem is in the child content, where you have fixed with (which is more than parents), that's why it's going offscreen.

You can add `overflow: hidden` on parent which have `margin: 0 auto` to see it's on center.

For children, remove fixed `width` and/or `min-width`, here you can use `%` instead of `px` for width.

Comment: Using % instead of px for width makes the text wrap on resize which I dont want. I tried to make the width less than the parents one, but for some reason 300 pixels isnt 300 pixels for the children elements

Comment: For this I will probably just let the text wrap around it and make it move under the side image at one point so it doesnt affect anything under it